# Need for inverter chain to decrease rise and fall time in a comparator

Tags: analog, inverter, comparator

I was designing a MOS comparator for my laboratory and I could not understand how an inverter chain helps in increases the slew rate across the load capacitor. And why an inverter chain ? why cant a single big inverter(High W/L ratio) serve the purpose ?

The overall system looks like the following with the comparator followed by the inverter
[image]

The inverter stage looks like this with inverter having an increases W/L in each stage by a factor close to 2.5
[image]

Comment: If you want a decent answer, include the schematic of whatever you're talking about.

Comment: My bad ! Have put it up with more details now.

Comment: The following advice is offered politely before the impolite people arrive :-) :-( : 
Schematics with high saturation coloured backgrounds will attract major complaints from readers. Either set the background to white or remove it on some manner. The version I have added as an example is still very ugly but much easier on eye & brain. Labels/text should be larger so people with average to worse eyesight can read them. Edit / remove / replace the diagram I added as desired - only there as an example.

Comment: Turn off the grid too, before taking a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sure, I understand. Sorry for the inconvenience , will do it this way from next time.

Comment: @transistor Sure will do so too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On chip circuitry is often designed to drive only very small loads. In order to increase the driving strength a buffer is needed.

Adding a single buffer with a high W/L ratio would serve that purpose, but due to its size it would again present a high load to the first stage of the comparator and thereby limiting its speed.

It can be shown that instead of using a single buffer a chain of buffers with increasing W/L results in a faster circuit, when the size of the driven buffer is only a few times the size of the driving buffer.

For this so-called *tapered buffer* the optimum ratio between two stages would be e (~ 2.718..), in practive however larger ratios are used to keep the number of stages lower while still achieving a decent speed.

Comment: This might sound lame but still let me ask , how does a buffer increase the driving strength which is nothing but current ? So I think its just  like a PMOS connected with the load (NMOS is turned off) and thus this has very high current capability  because the "on" resistance of PMOS is low and therefore it can supply the slew as quickly as possible ? And a bigger PMOS with bigger W will increase the Id since W is directly proportional to Id in the triode region equation . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, as you wrote, the driving strength (=amount of current it can deliver) is proportional to W. But the input capacitance of the inverter is also proportional to W. So a bigger inverter has a greater driving strength but presents also a larger load.

Comment: Sure and a larger load in the sense it takes more time to  switch the device on and off ? So in each stage there will be a delay ? Wouldn't this affect the slew rate also in a way ??

Comment: Yes, there is a delay in each stage. But the overall delay is still reduced. The slew rate is increased.